# Apply arithmetic transformation on a text file column bash

Tags: bash, recursion, awk, calculated-columns, arithmetic-expressions

I have large `csv` text files with multiple columns and I would like to apply an arithmetic transformation on, say, `column11` using variables in `column6` and `column12`.

The transformation would be as follows:

```
column11=column11*1000.*column12./(8.314*(column6+273.15))
```

where `.*` and `./` respectively denote elementwise multiplication and division of the values in each row.

Here is a sample of what the input text files look like:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.00",59841,0.327,3.275,1.89275,32.048,9,2435.477,2308.886,15.03365,31.2365067891251,98.7333,253
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.10",59842,0.086,3.56975,2.20325,32.10205,10,2433.668,2298.364,15.03292,31.2299567962211,98.7473,253
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.20",59843,0.26575,3.343,1.8285,32.06717,11,2433.833,2294.418,15.03119,31.2436473758837,98.72864,253
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.30",59844,-0.1915,3.28175,1.793,32.12122,12,2433.668,2280.608,15.02593,31.2410875853554,98.7333,253
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.40",59845,-0.20375,3.447,2.0135,32.08286,13,2433.833,2276.991,15.02812,31.2245602421307,98.73796,253
```

Ideally, the result would be saved to the same file and the process would be repeated by looping over `n` files.

A solution or some ideas in `awk`, `cut/paste` or just `bash` would be of great help.

Comment: What are the two dots in your mathematical expression?

Comment: remove the dots, replace "column" to "$" and run `awk -F, '{...}1' file > outputfile`, where `...` is your code after replacements.

Comment: A glance at any awk man page or any googled example would answer this question. Put a tiny bit of effort in.

Comment: @karakfa Thanks. It worked:                                                           a_files=(path/to/files/*.csv)
for ((i=0; i<"${#a_files[@]}"; i++)); do
awk -F, '{$11=$11*1000*$12/(8.314*($6+273.15))}1' "${a_files[i]}" > filenew"$i".csv
done                                                                                                              Will accept it if you move it to the answer section.

Comment: Look up the FILENAME attribute / variable for awk and you can do it without bash at all

Comment: @grail Thanks. Will keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: @Cyrus elementwise multiplication

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can write the main loop without arrays

```
 for f in path/to/files/*.csv
 do
    awk -F, '...' "$f" > "processed_$f"
 done
```